# SimpleFlatMapper object to object mapping

Tags: java, comparison, pojo

The SimpleFlatMapper library has the ability to map between data and POJO objects but what I would like to find out if it can map between a POJO object and a Map?

This is so that I can use it in a library (https://github.com/markash/komparator) that I am busy with performs comparisons and the ultimate goal is to be able to do the following:-

```
List<BusinessPojo> firstList = ...;
DataRecordSet recordSet01 = 
ObjectParser
   .mapTo(Map.class)
   .stream(firstList, convertToDataRecord)
   .collect(DataRecordSet.collect);

List<BusinessPojo> secondList = ...;
DataRecordSet recordSet02 = 
ObjectParser
   .mapTo(Map.class)
   .stream(secondList, convertToDataRecord)
   .collect(DataRecordSet.collect);

List<DataDifferences> results = recordSet01.compareWith(recordSet02);
```

The visual end result is https://mpashworth.wordpress.com/2017/07/09/calculating-string-differences/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not support that outside the box, there is no implementation supporting Map as a source or target at the moment.

I assume you would like to have a map each property to a key - value pair in the map with the key as some form of normalized key path, kind of a flattened JSON.

You could implement your own mapper, but it's not that trivial, what would be the type of the value?

You might be better off looking at a POJO -> Json -> flatten json transformation.

Saying that in theory it's doable, might have a look at it.